# Amount of work required for pulling rope problem

Tags: calculus, physics, applications

50 m rope with 8 millimeters in diameter is dangling from an edge. density of rope =40 g/m. how much work to pull it up to edge?

// I've seen different variations of this problem, but I am unsure of how to setup as following along with the "Pumping liquid out of tank" classic problem, I don't see the need for p * g in the work formula here.

// The work formula I am referring to and am thinking I would use:
Work = [Integral from b to a] (p*g *cross section area *lifting distance)dy

// I also notice that there is a diameter mentioned here, which I am not sure we would need.

Would someone please show me how to setup this integral properly?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use $mgh$ , find $m=\rho V$

Comment: Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is to treat it as moving the total mass of the rope a height from the cg of the rope to the edge. That is, mgh where $m = 50\cdot 40/1000$ kg, $g = 9.81$ and $h = 25$ m.

If you want to go the calculus route, set it up as a series of infinitely thin discs being raised different heights:

Mass of each disc is $\pi\cdot .004^2\cdot \frac{.04}{\pi\cdot .004^2}dx = .04 \ dx$

Distance each disc travels is $x$ from  $0$ to $50$.

$$W = \int_0^{50} mgx \ dx$$
$$W = \int_0^{50} .04\cdot 9.81x \ dx$$

$W = .02\cdot 9.81(x)^2$

$W = .02\cdot 9.81(50)^2$

$W = 490.5$ Joules

Comment: Hi again Phil, really saving my life this weekend. Because I have not yet taken physics, I'd like to stick to the calc approach. I see that you are using what seems like circular cross section area and then multiplying it with .04/pi*.004^2. Where are you getting this part of the equation? Also are we just using standard 1000kg for density and 9.8 m/s for acceleration with gravity? Thanks again for your concise explanations.

Comment: The mass of each disc is the cross sectional area $pi*r^2$ times the thickness dx times the density, which is the mass per meter length $(40/1000)$ divided by the cross sectional area $pi*r^2$, which gives density in mass per cubic meter. Conveniently the $pi*r^2$s cancel leaving $.04$ dx kg. The density on its own is $\frac{.04}{(pi*r^2)} = \frac{.04}{(pi*.004^2)}$ which comes out to be $795.775$ kg/m^3. I used $9.81$ for g.

Comment: it's density! ok great thanks so much Phil. I hope you enjoy your weekend.