# How much work is required to lift the rope?

Tags: calculus

A 5 meter rope is lying on the floor and has a mass which applies a force of 40 N in total. How much work is required to lift up one end of the rope to a height of 3 meters?

I tried doing 40 * 3 = 120, but this was wrong. I also tried 40(5-3) = 80, but this was also wrong. I even tried (40/5)*(3) = 24, however, this was wrong as well.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Near duplicate:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2850306/amount-of-work-required-for-pulling-rope-problem

Comment: When you lift the end, you don't lift the *full* segment to the height of the end.

Comment: What would the equation look like then, because I am not sure what to do?

Comment: Think about the *center of mass* of the lifted segment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: If you lifted a 10-foot rope so that one end is 10 feet off the ground, then the center of mass will have been lifted JUST TO 5 FEET.  You have NOT lifted the WHOLE rope to 10 feet.  Clear now?

Comment: Once you figure this out, then what happens next?

Comment: The work is the force times the displacement *OF THE CENTER OF MASS*.  Over and out.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a height of h meters,
the suspended mass exerts a force of 40h/5 N = 8h N.
Raising it dh higher takes 8h.dh work.
To lift it 3 m requires $\int_0^3$8h.dh Nm of work.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thank you!